# How to pass multiple parameters list in json with android, syntax issue

Tags: android, json

I have to pass a json object with a method and multiple parameters

the object must have this form

```
{"method":"startSession","params":"["email" "testmail@test.it", "password" "1234", "stayLogged" "1", "idClient" "IPHONE"]"}
```

My code in android to send this object is

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(BASE_URI);

           JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 

            String email="testmail@test.it";
            String emailRic="email"+" "+"\""+email+"\"";
            String password="1234";
            String passwordRic="password"+" "+"\""+password+"\"";
            String stayLogged="1";
            String stayLoggedRic="stayLogged"+" "+"\""+stayLogged+"\"";
            String idClient="ANDROID";
            String idClientRic="idClient"+" "+"\""+idClient+"\"";

            try {
                List<String> accessParameters=new ArrayList<String>();
                accessParameters.add(emailRic);
                accessParameters.add(passwordRic);
                accessParameters.add(stayLoggedRic);
                accessParameters.add(idClientRic);
                String par=accessParameters.toString();

                json.put("method", "startSession");
                json.put("params", par);                  

                JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray(); 
                postjson.put(json); 
                httppost.setHeader("json",json.toString());
                httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson); 
                System.out.print(json); 
                HttpResponse response = mClient.execute(httppost); 

                if(response != null){
                    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    System.out.println("the answer is:\n"+sb);
                    String line = null;

                try {
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            is.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
               // text = sb.toString();
                }
               // tv.setText(text);

            }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
```

But this send an object with the wrong form

```
{"method":"startSession","params":"[\"email\" \"testmail@test.it\", \"password\" \"1234\", \"restaConnesso\" \"1\", \"idClient\" \"IPHONE\"]"}
```

(I have seen this in the debugger)

if I try to remove the value \" from the piece of code

```
   String email="testmail@test.it";
            String emailRic="email"+" "+"\""+email+"\"";
            String password="1234";
            String passwordRic="password"+" "+"\""+password+"\"";
            String stayLogged="1";
            String stayLoggedRic="stayLogged"+" "+"\""+stayLogged+"\"";
            String idClient="ANDROID";
            String idClientRic="idClient"+" "+"\""+idClient+"\"";
```

The object sent assume the form

```
  {"method":"startSession","params":"[email testmail@test.it, password 1234, restaConnesso 1, idClient IPHONE]"}
```

**how can I sent the json with exacty this sintax???**

```
{"method":"startSession","params":"["email" "testmail@test.it", "password" "1234", "stayLogged" "1", "idClient" "IPHONE"]"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);

    //Firstly declare & create a json object from the desired json as a whole.

/* How to create Json*/
JSONObject jObjectData = new JSONObject();


    // Create Json Object using Facebook Data
    jObjectData.put("method", "startSession");

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("email");
    list.add("testmail@test.it");
etc... ....
    JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(list);
     jObjectData.put("params", jsArray);

    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(jObjectData.toString());
    httpost.setEntity(stringEntity);
    httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    response = httpclient.execute(httpost, responseHandler);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't understand how exactly I can use the piece of code that you have posted.

Could you tell me more??... thx

Comment: I have tried it but doesn't work... 

if I try to print string after 
JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(list);
     jObjectData.put("params", jsArray);

placing 


        String out=jsArray.toString();
        System.out.print(out);

doesn't print anything

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Create Json object for set parameter*/
JSONObject jObjectData = new JSONObject();


// set your first parameter name
jObjectData.put("parameter1", "startSession");

ArrayList<JSONObject> list = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
// for 1 parameter   
JSONObject jObjectData1 = new JSONObject();
jObjectData1.put("email","testmail@test.it");
jObjectData1.put("password","1234");
jObjectData1.put("stayLogged","1");
jObjectData1.put("idClient","IPHONE");
list.add(jObjectData1);

JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(list);

// set your second parameter has more value
jObjectData.put("parameter2", jsArray);
```

jObjectData string is look like below string:-

```
{"parameter1":"startSession",
"parameter2": [{ "email": "testmail@test.it", 
            "password": "1234", 
            "stayLogged": "1", 
            "idClient": "IPHONE"
           }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but, isn't the problem the fact that you are trying to send an array but are instead sending a string?

Original:

```
   {"method":"startSession",
    "params":"["email" "testmail@test.it", "password" "1234", "stayLogged" "1", "idClient" "IPHONE"]"}
```

Should be something like this instead (no quotes around the array):

```
   {"method":"startSession",
    "params": ["email" "testmail@test.it", "password" "1234", "stayLogged" "1", "idClient" "IPHONE"]}
```

Edit: Actually I think you actually want a nested object:

```
   {"method":"startSession",
    "params": { "email": "testmail@test.it", 
                "password": "1234", 
                "stayLogged": "1", 
                "idClient": "IPHONE"
               }
   }
```

No?

Edit #2: You should take a look at how to properly use JSONArray and JSONObject, [this page](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples#Example_5-1_-_Combination_of_JSON_primitives,_JSON_object_and_JS) has some good examples.

Comment: Yes, right I want a nested object. But I don't know how I can write a working code for this json {"method":"startSession",
    "params": { "email": "testmail@test.it", 
                "password": "1234", 
                "stayLogged": "1", 
                "idClient": "IPHONE"
               }
   }